# Как в ссылке на картинку добавить размер?

Tags: php, html, php7

Вот есть такая ссылка в виде, но без парам. размера картинок.

```html
<?= Html::img("@web/images/products/{$hit->img}", ['alt' => $hit->name])?>
```

ДО этого была эта т.е. выводилась только главная картинка

```html
 <?= Html::img($mainImg->getUrl('240x180'), ['alt' => $hit->name])
```

Как добавить параметр размеров ('240x180') к первой ссылке?

```html
<div class="recommended_items">
    <!--recommended_items-->
    <h2 class="title text-center">recommended items</h2>

    <div id="recommended-item-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php $count = count($hits); $i = 0; foreach($hits as $hit): ?>
<?php if($i % 3 == 0): ?>
    <div class="item <?php if($i == 0) echo 'active' ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-products">
                    <div class="productinfo text-center">
                        


                    <?= Html::img("@web/images/products/{$hit->img } ", ['alt' => $hit->name])?>

 
                        <h2>$<?= $hit->price?></h2>
                        <p><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $hit->id])?>"><?= $hit->name?></a></p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php $i++; if($i % 3 == 0 || $i == $count): ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <a class="left recommended-item-control" href="#recommended-item-carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="right recommended-item-control" href="#recommended-item-carousel" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div><!--/recommended_items-->
```

Comment: `<? Html::img(('@web/images/products/'.$hit->img)->getUrl('240x180'), ['alt' => $hit->name]) ?>`?

Comment: @Let's say Pie так уже пробовал, выбрасывает "Call to a member function getUrl() on string"

Comment: Можно узнать, что находится в `$mainImg`, сделайте `var_dump($mainImg);` ?

Comment: @Let's say Pie   в $mainImg там выводилась гл.картинка из счетчика, где   $mainImg = $product->getImage();   но сейчас этого парам. нет в коде и он не нужен.  выводятся все товары с полем "hit"  только отм. в бд

Comment: Ну посмотрите что лежит в `$product->getImage();`, возможно полная ссылка там, уточните и проверьте, сделайте так же

Comment: @Let's say Pie там этого парам. getImage тоже нет сейчас, я выложил код блока под вопросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?= Html::img("@web/images/products/{$hit->img}", ['alt' => $hit->name, 'width' => 280, 'height' => 180])?>
```